# How do i use regex in javascript to find three periods inside of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok, this is probably a simple regex but i am not familiar with them.  I have a bunch of strings like this: '11.9.2.1 Fusion' or '11.9.1 Fusion' etc...  All of them have ' Fusion' at the end of them.  I am trying to find only the ones with three periods (or four sets of numbers) in them.  This is some pseudo code like what i have:

```
$(xml).find("Asset").each(function(){
    var projectName = $(this).find("Attribute[name='SecurityScope.Name']").text();
    if(projectName.match(where-ive-been-putting-regex-statements)){
        var patch = true;
    }else{
        var patch = false;
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches strings like '11.9.2.1 Fusion':

```
projectName.match(/^(\d+\.){3}\d+ Fusion$/)
```

Comment: Awesome, this works!  Thanks for the quick replies everyone!  Also +1 for using my code in your example.

Comment: No need to put the `\d` inside a character class.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? - `/(\d+\.){3}\d+/`

It matches 3 groups of numbers (at least 1 digit) followed by a period and a fourth number.

Comment: ooh, I like that - more concise than my answer

Comment: Yes, but where's the `"fusion"`?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s+Fusion
```

Matches 4 groups of any digit (one or more) separated by a literal dot, followed by one or more whitespace, followed by literal string "Fusion"

Matches: 11.9.2.1 Fusion
But does not match: 11.9.1 Fusion

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jqvtp/

Answer (score 1):

A regex to match a string that contains three periods would be

```
.*\..*\..*\..*
```

(where the first and last `.*`s may be superfluous depending on whether your regex engine offers a "contains"-style match.)

The critical part here is that `.` by itself is a character wildcard so will match *anything*.  Escaping it with the backslash turns it into a match for a literal period.

So what we have is (with line breaks for explanation)

```
.*   // Match any character, any number of times.  Then:
\.   // Match a literal period.  Followed by:
.*   // Any character, any number of times.  Followed by: (etc...)
```

Comment: It looks like that is returning true in both cases: with two periods AND with three periods.

Comment: This can't work, because .* actually matches a normal dot as well.

Comment: @Niko - that's fine in general.  You'd only need to prevent that (by replacing it by `[^.]*`) if you wanted to match a string with **exactly** three periods.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+ Fusion
```

Comment: He said three periods, not four.

Comment: No need to put the `\d` inside a character class.